# Getting error in running odata webservice for experience manager

Tags: 2013, siteedit

While running odata service for EM I'm getting this error in `cd_core` log file

```
StorageManagerFactory - Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.configure(CacheChannel.java:251) ~[cd_cache.jar:na]
at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.createCacheChannel(CacheChannel.java:230) ~[cd_cache.jar:na]
at com.tridion.cache.CacheFactory.configure(CacheFactory.java:222) ~[cd_cache.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.configuration.CacheConfigurationLoader.configure(CacheConfigurationLoader.java:17) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor.checkSessionWrapperAvailability(WritableODataClaimProcessor.java:155) [cd_preview_ambient.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor.guaranteeInitialized(WritableODataClaimProcessor.java:141) [cd_preview_ambient.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor.onRequestStart(WritableODataClaimProcessor.java:55) [cd_preview_ambient.jar:na]
at com.tridion.ambientdata.Engine.onRequestStart(Engine.java:147) [cd_ambient.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

I'm using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're just "half" configured to use JMS as your cache invalidation provider (judging by `javax.jms.JMSException`). You should NOT use cache for the session preview webservice, as all this data is temporary and session specific anyway, so I'd start by changing your `cd_storage_conf.xml` to disable cache, then restart and try again.

Comment: Thnaks Nuno after disabling object cache in cd_storage_config.xml it works

Comment: Now i m getting another problem preview Update is keep asking for The preview for this page is not up to date in cd_preview log i m getting this error ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction

Comment: Please create a new question for this, questions in comments are not useful for others - and try searching for that same error, maybe others had it before

Comment: Abdul - as you have said that it now works, I'd suggest you give Nuno the credit for this by accepting his answer.